# How to transform transformed object in matplotlib without recursion?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am using translations in matplotlib animation and I am calling method drawObject() every 20 ms. My problem is, that td2dis (when I print it) consist from some data, and 1 Matrix, in first method call. In second call, its data, and 2 matrixes. And so on. So when I am in number N method call, I have N matrixes. And they work recursively. And because of this recursion my aimation die after few seconds. Is here any built possibility, how to count (maybe only multiply?) these matrixes? or reduce them to only 1?
**So I want transform transformed object without recursion. Is it possible?**

```
td2dis = ax.transData

def drawObjects():
    global td2dis
    ...
    tr = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(coords[0], coords[1], angle)
    t=td2dis+tr
    td2dis=t
    ...
```

**Printed variable td2dis with matrix with data in 1st method call**

```
CompositeGenericTransform(TransformWrapper(BlendedAffine2D(IdentityTransform(),IdentityTransform())), CompositeGenericTransform(BboxTransformFrom(TransformedBbox(Bbox('array([[ -19.5      ,  -10.7983871],\n       [ 221.5      ,  140.7983871]])'), TransformWrapper(BlendedAffine2D(IdentityTransform(),IdentityTransform())))), BboxTransformTo(TransformedBbox(Bbox('array([[ 0.125,  0.25 ],\n       [ 0.9  ,  0.9  ]])'), BboxTransformTo(TransformedBbox(Bbox('array([[ 0.,  0.],\n       [ 8.,  6.]])'), Affine2D(array([[ 80.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,  80.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   1.]]))))))))
```

**Printed td2dis with matrixes with data in 4th step**

```
CompositeGenericTransform(CompositeGenericTransform(CompositeGenericTransform(CompositeGenericTransform(CompositeGenericTransform(TransformWrapper(BlendedAffine2D(IdentityTransform(),IdentityTransform())), CompositeGenericTransform(BboxTransformFrom(TransformedBbox(Bbox('array([[ -19.5      ,  -10.7983871],\n       [ 221.5      ,  140.7983871]])'), TransformWrapper(BlendedAffine2D(IdentityTransform(),IdentityTransform())))), BboxTransformTo(TransformedBbox(Bbox('array([[ 0.125,  0.25 ],\n       [ 0.9  ,  0.9  ]])'), BboxTransformTo(TransformedBbox(Bbox('array([[ 0.,  0.],\n       [ 8.,  6.]])'), **Affine2D(array(**[[ 80.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,  80.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   1.]])))))))), Affine2D(array([[ 0.99968918, -0.02493069,  6.97023765],
       [ 0.02493069,  0.99968918, -7.08231365],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]]))), Affine2D(array([[ 0.99968918, -0.02493069,  6.99869385],
       [ 0.02493069,  0.99968918, -7.84282183],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]]))), Affine2D(array([[ 0.99968918, -0.02493069,  6.94884054],
       [ 0.02493069,  0.99968918, -7.04407025],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]]))), Affine2D(array([[ 0.99968918, -0.02493069,  6.94929398],
       [ 0.02493069,  0.99968918, -7.04925306],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]])))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, tr has methodes set_matrix and get_matrix